# from geopy.geocoders.google import GQueryError ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders.google'

Tags: django, geopy

I am getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy.geocoders.google'

from this code on  `from geopy.geocoders.google import GQueryError`. The error is a show in the picture, also.

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from urllib.request import URLError 
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
from django.contrib.gis import geos
from geopy.geocoders.google import GQueryError
from geopy import geocoders

# Create your models here.

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField(u"longitude/latitude",
                                     geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.location:
            address = u'%s %s' % (self.city, self.address)
            address = address.encode('utf-8')
            geocoder = GoogleV3()
            try:
                _, latlon = geocoder.geocode(address)
            except (URLError, GQueryError, ValueError):
                pass
            else:
                point = "POINT(%s %s)" % (latlon[1], latlon[0])
                self.location = geos.fromstr(point)
        super(Shop, self).save()
```